# Near-ring spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras, homotopy-theory

$\newcommand{\la}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\leftarrow\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ua}[1]{\bigg\uparrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{\mathrm{sgn}}$A near-ring ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-ring), [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/near-ring)) "is" a ring in which addition is not necessarily commutative, and in which only half of the distributivity conditions hold (e.g. for "left near-rings" we can have $a(b+c)=ab+ac$, though not necessarily $(a+b)c=ac+bc$). Similarly, a near-semiring "is" a near-ring without additive inverses.

It's [possible](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/925154/603207) to define left/right near-rings (resp. near-semirings) as monoids in $\mathsf{Grp}$ (resp. $\mathsf{Mon}$) equipped with one of the tensor products $\triangleleft,\triangleright\colon\mathsf{Grp}\times\mathsf{Grp}\to\mathsf{Grp}$ defined by
\begin{align*}
G\triangleleft H  &= \coprod_{h\in H}G,\\
G\triangleright H &= \coprod_{g\in G}H.
\end{align*}

Until recently, I was personally not very interested in near-rings, due mainly to finding the usual examples to be a bit hard to come by, but then I noticed that near-rings in contexts other than $\mathsf{Set}$ are quite interesting, and seem to include objects such as the [braid category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/braid+category) $\mathbb{B}$ and the $k$-fold loop space of the $k$-sphere $\Omega^k S^k$.

---

Indeed, the geometric realisation
$$\displaystyle\coprod_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathrm{B}\mathrm{B}_n\simeq\coprod_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathrm{UConf}_{n}(\mathbb{R}^2),$$
of the braid category $\mathbb{B}$ seems to be a natural example of something we could call an "$(\mathbb{E}_2,\mathbb{E}_1)$-near-semiring space", where:

- The additive structure is induced by $(n,m)\mapsto n+m$ and by the group morphisms
  $$\oplus\colon\mathrm{B}_n\times\mathrm{B}_m\to\mathrm{B}_{n+m}$$
  given by juxtaposition of braids:

[image]

- The multiplicative structure is induced by $(n,m)\mapsto nm$ and by the group morphisms
  $$\otimes\colon\mathrm{B}_n\times\mathrm{B}_m\to\mathrm{B}_{nm}$$
  given by sending $(\sigma,\tau)$ to the braid obtained as follows:

  - Partition the $nm$ strands into $n$ subsets of $m$ strands;
  - Braid each of the $m$ strands according to $\tau$;
  - Braid the $n$ subsets according to $\sigma$;

For example, the product of the braids $\sigma$ and $\tau$ depicted as

[image]

is given by

[image]

while $\tau\otimes\sigma$ is the braid

[image]

- The additive braiding
  $$\beta^{\mathbb{B},\oplus}_{n,m}\colon n\oplus m\to m\oplus n$$
  is given by the morphism of $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{B}}(n+m,n+m)\cong\mathrm{B}_{n+m}$ corresponding to the [braid](https://web.science.mq.edu.au/%7Estreet/JS1.pdf#page=16)

[image]

This is indeed a braiding:

- Naturality is given by the [equality](https://web.science.mq.edu.au/%7Estreet/JS1.pdf#page=16)

[image]

- The left hexagon equality is [the equality of braids](https://web.science.mq.edu.au/%7Estreet/JS1.pdf#page=17)

[image]

- The right hexagon equality is the [same equality as above,but flipped](https://web.science.mq.edu.au/%7Estreet/JS1.pdf#page=17):

[image]

The additive and multiplicative structures above are in a sense a lift of the ones in the groupoid of finite sets and permutations
$$\coprod_{n=0}^\infty\mathrm{B}\Sigma_n\simeq\coprod_{n=0}^\infty\mathrm{UConf}_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty)$$
along the maps $\mathrm{B}_n\to\Sigma_n$ sending a braid to its underlying permutation.

They also relate to the additive structure of $\Pi_{\leq1}(\Omega^2S^2)$ via the abelianisation map $\deg\colon\mathrm{B}_n\to\mathbb{Z}$, satisfying the relations
\begin{align*}
\deg(\sigma\oplus\tau)  &= \deg(\sigma)+\deg(\tau),\\
\deg(\sigma\otimes\tau) &= m^2\deg(\sigma)+n\deg(\tau).
\end{align*}

(An interesting aside is that the compositions
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\mathbb{B} & \ra{} & \Pi_{\leq1}(\Omega^2S^2)\\
\da{}& & \da{}\\
\mathbb{F} & \ra{} & \Pi_{\leq1}(\Omega^\infty\mathbb{S}),
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}{c}
\mathrm{B}_{nm} & \ra{\deg} & \mathbb{Z}\\
\da{}& & \da{\mathrm{mod}\text{ }2}\\
\Sigma_{nm} & \ra{\mathrm{sgn}} & \mathbb{Z}/2\\
\end{array}
$$
play well with multiplication of braids in that we have
\begin{align*}
\deg(\sigma\otimes\tau) &=      m^2\deg(\sigma)+n\deg(\tau)\\
                    &\equiv m\deg(\sigma)+n\deg(\tau)\ \text{(mod 2})\\
                    &\equiv m\sgn(\sigma)+n\sgn(\tau)\ \text{(mod 2})\\
                    &\equiv \sgn(\sigma\otimes\tau)  \ \text{(mod 2}),
\end{align*}
where we used Fermat's little theorem for $p=2$.)

---

**Question.** Is there a natural definition of an "$(\mathbb{E}_n,\mathbb{E}_k)$-near-(semi/)ring space" recovering the examples of $\coprod_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathrm{B}\mathrm{B}_n$ and $\Omega^kS^k$?

(In particular, are there suitable analogues of the tensor products $\triangleleft$ and $\triangleright$ above for $\mathsf{Mon}_{\mathbb{E}_k}(\mathcal{S})$ and $\mathsf{Grp}_{\mathbb{E}_k}(\mathcal{S})$?)

Comment: Is the multiplication map $B_m \times B_n\to B_{mn}$ really $E_2$-commutative?

Comment: @GregoryArone It indeed isn't! I've updated the question to correct this mistake. Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems the braid multiplication map $\mathrm{B}_{n}\times\mathrm{B}_{m}\to\mathrm{B}_{nm}$ above appears in the theory of braided operads under the name "block braid". See e.g. [Yau, Infinity Operads and Monoidal Categories with Group Equivariance, Example 5.1.13](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.03839.pdf#page=79) or [Vallette, Homotopy of Operads and Grothendieck–T Groups, Proposition 5.1.2, Item (b)](https://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/~vallette/Homotopy%20of%20Operads%20and%20Grothendieck-Teichmuller%20Groups_%20Part%201.pdf#page=214).